# javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(); what is this function doing, and how can I replicate it?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, button, webforms

I'm trying to put a search button on a page that behaves the same as the button on the parent site. The sites are on different domains, so I may have to change some of the button's functionality. I'm trying to figure out what the button on the parent site is doing so that I can replicate it.

This is the HTML for the search bar and submit button on the parent site:

```
<div id="ctl00_pnlSearch002" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'ctl00_btnSearch002')">

    <div class="utilities floatRight">
        <ul>
            <li class="searchButton"><input type="image" name="ctl00$btnSearch002" id="ctl00_btnSearch002" src="/images/design002/btn_search.jpg" style="width: 30px; height: 22px; border: none;"></li>
            <li class="search"><input name="ctl00$txtSearch" type="text" id="ctl00_txtSearch" value="Search" onblur="if (value == '') {value = 'Search'}" onfocus="if (value == 'Search') {value =''}"></li>
            <li class="paddingL"><a href="javascript:textResizer.doResize(1)" class="aPlus">A+</a><a href="javascript:textResizer.doResize(-1)" class="aMinus">A-</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>              
</div>
```

So far I've pasted the same html onto my new page, but the submit button doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they have set the `DefaultButton` to be the search button on the form.

Within WebForms you can specify a `DefaultButton` so that when a user is entering data if they hit enter it will default to that button.

[**DefaultButton**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.defaultbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: OK, so is there a way I can figure out what action that button is performing? If I can figure out how to translate that to "action='xxx'", I think I can replicate the behavior.

Comment: @user3784238 It is replicating a button click on the button with the id of ctl00_btnSearch002 when they hit enter. Do you have the source code are you replicating the functionality within WebForms?

Comment: No, I don't have the source code :( This is the site that has the search button I'm trying to emulate: http://www.munsonhomehealth.org/

Comment: @user3784238 Yes, it looks like they're using the DefaulButton in that. If you look at the link above it contains a simple example. All it does is makes sure the search button is pressed(form submitted) if they're typing into the search box or otherwise hitting enter can either do nothing or submit another form on the page.

Comment: Right, but when the search button is clicked, what action is it calling? If I could figure out that, say, it's going to "musonhomehealth.org/search/?q=blah" I could add that functionality to my own button, but I can't figure out where the search button is submitting to.

Comment: Typing `a` and hitting enter goes too: `http://www.munsonhomehealth.org/search/?sid=4&cx=014782065546096959900:nzah0grwr_k&cof=FORID%3A11&ie=UTF-8&q=a&sa=Search`

Comment: well yeah... but all of that extra stuff in the querystring is getting added somewhere, and I can't just copy and paste the "sid=4&cx=014782065546096959900:nzah0grw‌​r_k&cof=FORID%3A11&ie=UTF-8&" part

Comment: @user3784238 Sorry but it's impossible to tell what they are doing in there code server-side, the original question was what was the javascript function doing and all that does is simulate pressing the button when you hit enter. You could be on a very long time guessing what they do on the server.

Comment: That's what I was wondering, so it's just not possible I guess :\